# WPF versus Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When creating a new GUI, is WPF the preferred choice over Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909/when-creating-a-new-gui-is-wpf-the-preferred-choice-over-windows-forms)

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages between using WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) over Windows Forms?
2. What are the considerations that need to be made when choosing between the two?