# Nedd we switching from Winforms to WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms

Is there is any ***need to pass*** existing (or developing) **projects from WinForms to WPF?**
or even Silverlight?

If the project is OK, worth it to be switched in WPF? Can Silverlight replace WPF in the future?

I am asking because there a rumors that Microsoft will abandon WinForm (maintenance and support) for WPF and Silverlight. I believe Winforms will be supported as longer Windows will be?!...

Will the development of Winforms obsolete in a lot of years?

Comment: Without a qualified reference, to me this question qualifies as "subjective and argumentative"

Comment: This question calls for some intense speculation.  It doesn't belong on StackOverflow.com.

Comment: Indeed. "Someone on the Internet said the sky might fall! Will it?"

Comment: @Piskvors: If there was a science forum, that question could be discussed. My question was if there is any need to pass existing (or developing) projects from Forms to WPF.

Comment: Yes, winforms will most likely be dropped. It will probably happen similar to how VB 6 is now phased out, so development stops, then maintanence and support will go out in perhaps ten years from now. By that time Windows will not look at all what it does now, and winforms will probably not even be capable to produce an UI that works...

Comment: @Guffa : can we have a reference for this? It sounds speculative to me.

Comment: @spender: Yes, it's speculative. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913417/will-winforms-be-deprecated-in-favor-of-wpf
 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640633/is-it-better-to-use-wpf-over-winforms
 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388711/when-is-winforms-the-correct-choice-vs-wpf
 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504014/wpf-winforms-or-something-else
 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms
 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897945/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wpf-over-winforms
 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149537/nedd-we-switching-from-winforms-to-wpf

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has certainly never said that, and there are new Winforms features in VS2010.

Consider the fact that their C++ UI technology from 1992, MFC, continues to be shipped, supported and extended with every version of VS.

Comment: so there is any urgent need to pass existing (or developping) projects from Forms to WPF?..

Comment: To reiterate: MFC, nearly 20 year old UI technology, still being enhanced in new versions of VS. Doesn't seem that urgent.