# Is software in winforms still being developed?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will WinForms be deprecated in favor of WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913417/will-winforms-be-deprecated-in-favor-of-wpf)

Hi,

I'm making winforms application in my company and I want to know, if software in winforms is still being developed? I don't want a discussion, I only want to know if is the time to change specialization.

Comment: What are your proposed alternatives?

Comment: WPF, ajax web apps, RIAs... those are the alternatives.

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate of the one being suggested, and should not be closed for that reason. Although hokey, it is a legitimate question.

Comment: WinForms will likely never die and hang around like every other depreciated technology (such as COBOL and ASP Classic) until the end of time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is still developing, even though WPF begins to gather pace.

Comment: It's been gathering pace for a good 3 years now.  The Vista Bridge and Windows API Code Pack support Winforms as well as WPF.

Answer (score 1):

The question of is it "still" being developed will, of course, be answered with a resounding **yes**. The reason for that is that there has certainly not been enough time passed for all older apps to completely die off.

To prove this point, the question "Are apps written in VB6 still being developed?" would get the *exact* same answer.

Now, if your question is: "**Should** a completely new application that is meant to be a thick client be written using WinForms?" then I would answer... "No, you should use WPF instead."

Comment: VB is not exactly analogous to Windows Forms.  It is true that VB is still in use.  However, it is pretty obsolete.  Windows Forms is not nearly in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

IT is obvious YES Windows Form application developing and there are too many new application which developed by WinForm and the developer has to support it, and also create new application by that.

there are many reason which WinForm still supports by Microsoft. But Microsoft Recommands to use WPF to create more better apps

Answer (score 0):

Winforms has not changed much lately because it is a mature technology that does exactly what you need it to do.  It can be used to create solid, stable, highly functional Windows applications.  There are literally thousands of commercial and open source UI components that you can plug into your Windows forms application.  Many developers know it well.  Windows Forms applications can take advantage of popular design patterns, like MVC, so they can be unit tested and easily maintained.  It is still  a perfectly good choice for developing thick clients on the Windows platform.  I think we will see many new applications, especially in-house/corporate apps, being developed on Windows Forms for a very long time.

WPF is the new kid on the block and it is coming on fast.  I would certainly lean towards it in new applications.