# Do WPF projects takes more time to load than WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, wpf

Do WPF projects takes more time to load than WindowsForms?

Comment: Do you mean load in Visual Studio or load when the user runs the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms

Comment: I guessing yes, but I'm also guessing that Win32 executables take longer to load than DOS applications. It's the price of progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A small part of a longer answer by Ray Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms/1693774#1693774) (the rest is worth reading too):

> You do pay a price compared to
> WinForms, but it is a small one.
>
> - RAM can go up or down depending on your implementation. WPF stores its
>   data more efficiently so individual
>   objects are smaller, but there tend to
>   be more objects in WPF than in
>   WinForms so this balances out, and
>   either one can come out ahead.
> - CPU will go up compared to WinForms. In my experience, the actual
>   update of WPF objects onscreen takes
>   about 2x as much CPU as normal
>   WinForms rendering. If your
>   application spends most of its time
>   updating the screen, WPF may not be
>   for you. But in that case you're
>   probably not using WinForms either:
>   Most serious games are written
>   directly to DirectX.
> - Disk usage will be slightly less for WPF because it takes so much less
>   code than WinForms. The data will be
>   the same size, of course.
>
> One more note about CPU use:
> Animations and transforms (motion,
> translation, etc) is actually more
> efficient on WPF than in WinForms
> because of its retained mode storage.
> It is the initial getting of the
> objects up there that is slower