# .NET: What is WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF versus Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms)

What is WPF and how does it compare to WinForms?

Why would you use WPF instead of WinForms?