# Choosing between WPF and Windows Forms Applications

Tags: .net, vb.net-2010

Now I'm in position to start a new project. Until now I always choose the WFA.
Now I want to know what is the creteria of choosing WPF or WFA. 
What is the motivation for choose.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATIONS**

The project refers to:

- Handle incoming mails
- Crate a suitable invironment for the user (receiver)
- Following up the process in mails
- Closing the actions

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF versus Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms)

Comment: What is the project? Your question in its current form gives potential answerers very little information, not enough to give you a good substantive answer.

Comment: @slugster. Yes you have absolute right. That’s why I give those few details. In case are not enough please tell what else you want me to give you.

Comment: @Binary Worrier. Yes you may have right for dublication of the question. But as far as I read the "WPF versus Winforms" I see that it will be much better to start it with WPF. What is you opinion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

really, just use wpf, as it's better in all areas.. the only reason i'd go for winforms is you don't have the time to learn wpf..

Comment: I have the time But most of all I have you:)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to have the application be supported by or easily migrated to upcoming .NET versions? If yes, choose WPF.

Comment: I see that you're positive to WPF!