# what is the difference between a WPF app to a winforms app?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF versus Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms)

I have been using visual C# for a while now, I have made some apps in the window forms but never really explored the WPF apps. Based on what I have discovered it pretty much is the same as a winforms just in a different type of environment and the XML. So why is there such a WPF app? what makes it different form a winform and what is it mainly used for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms/202310#202310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons to move WPF. You will be able to find many reasons by simple google search. It's the new trend and when it comes to Windows application development the technology has been focusing to WPF rather than Winforms.

As Tom also has mentioned above [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms/202310#202310) thread gives you many points.

My opinion is there is no big reasons not to go for a WPF if somebody is going to develop a windows application from the scratch.

Comment: another question if you don't mind, can you make a website with WPF because it says new page and main page like a website.

Comment: You can't directly run a WPF Windows Application in Web. But you can create a WPF XBAP Application to run it inside the browser. But the issue is XBAP applications need .Net Framework to be installed in the client PC.

Comment: Look at here for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480223.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on your real need. Desktop oriented application tends to go with winform. Both get compiled by the same compiler to produce the same thing; both utilize the same resources to run on the target platform, but WPF has more graphics effects that many people would favor it from the start. Winform offers userfriendly design controls though.

Answer (score 0):

Some differences off the top of my head:

1. Separation of UI and 'code-behind', so that designers can allegedly design the UI while the developers develop the business logic.  A much cleaner separation than traditional WinForms.
2. Improved graphics rendering.  The vector graphics are vastly superior to WinForms graphics -- just zoom in on some letters in a WPF app vs. a WinForms app and you'll see sharp edges in the WinForms app, but smooth edges in the WPF app.  Pretty awesome.
3. A much more flexible UI model in WPF, where you can have buttons inside of lists which are inside of grids, since it's all just XAML.  WinForms requires you to build those types of controls and is much more limiting.

Those were just a few.  Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks all of you for the help, I think im going to start using WPF now since I know what it is.