# Design Pattern for a .NET 4.0 Winform Desktop application

Tags: .net, design-patterns, entity-framework-4.1, desktop-application

Can someone suggest a good proven/time tested design pattern for a winform desktop application in .NET 4.0? My application is going to be a pure business application.

I know there could be many "It depends", but still can someone give suggestions/URLs where I can find implemented samples?

Also, will EF help in reducing development time, if used? What other benefits does it offer from design perspective?

Comment: I don't think this question had to be closed.

Comment: it should be more constructive: What is the application main function?  What will be mainly use? What are the future of that application so we can point to technologies or ways of doing it? Does the application runs in a home (internet based) or only in a company (intranet) so we can take the resources into account... We can't make a good answer if the question is to abstract.

Comment: the main function of the app would be to import data from multiple sources, data will be analyzed, scrubbed and then reports will be generated from it. Does it help in giving more suggestions?

Comment: Also, there are no animations, graphics in the app

Answer (score 1):

For a windows application I would strongly suggest **Windows Presentation Foundation** as the start point as it gives you a fantastic division of concerns on what's UI and what's code, plus you can easily get a designer to give you the XAML and apply to your code without ever ruining your work as a developer.

Plus you will have the advantage in be easier to do a **Silverlight** version if you will ever need cross platforms (though the XAML for WPF is not the same for SL)

EF does really a good job this days, but there are much more ORM out there, like [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET), and **better than that**, if you know how to separate concerns, for example, create a Library that only handles the Database connection and queries, creating and using an Interface in your main program, using Inversion of Control, **today is EF**, but **tomorrow can be something completely different** and all you need to do is change a `.dll`.

Comment: As we don't have WPF skill set, we are recommended for NOT using WPF by our company. So, can u please suggest something for winforms.

Comment: Entity Framework will help you to reduce development time. Visual Studio can generate the business objects from a database. And it is very easy to bind WPF controls to those generated classes. See a [walkthrough at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465159.aspx)

Comment: Winforms is a pain :) that's why they invented WPF ;)

Comment: I can convince my superiors, if you can give some specific benefits of WPF over Winforms.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202079/wpf-versus-winforms/1693774#1693774