# WinForm vs WPF for POS UI using Microsoft Dynamics RMS

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, rms

**Microsoft Dynamics RMS**

I'm dealing with AddIn Creation and Custom POS Buttons (i.e. customization).

For development I am using mainly class library type project, and the dll created is Invoked from POS Machine (RMS). I use other .NET objects in my application but all are invoked through this class library.

I just wanted to know:

- Can we use WPF for UI instead of WinForms for the POS UI?

Please elaborate and discuss any problems we might face with this approach.

Comment: Which UI? The one on POS machine?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909/when-creating-a-new-gui-is-wpf-the-preferred-choice-over-windows-forms

Comment: Yeah !
POS Machine.
As We Deal with Class Library Project Type.
How Can we Invoke the WPF user Control

Comment: "Please elaborate and discuss any problems" sounds an awful lot like "I don't want to search for this myself, please do the work for me" ;-) just sayin'